# Usage of mozCaptureStream stop audio output of video element

Tags: javascript, firefox, mediastream

Call mozCaptureStream API on video tag causes to stop audio output

OS: Windows 10 (x64)
Browser: Mozilla Firefox 100.0.2 (64-bit)

Comment: Is there a question? Or are you using stack overflow instead of sticky notes?

Comment: @Bravo the question is there any fix available for this situation

Comment: what is the situation? Can you show some code that demonstrates the situation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [BUG 1178751](https://bugzil.la/1178751), Firefox does destroy the AudioSink from the original media element so that it's instead transferred into the newly produced MediaStream.

They're still working on it (after 7 years), and hopefully they'll fix it one day and stop prefixing `captureStream()`.

Until this day comes, you can use an AudioContext to play the MediaStream's audio:

```js
const vid = document.querySelector("video");
vid.onplay = (evt) => {
  const stream = vid.captureStream ? vid.captureStream() : vid.mozCaptureStreamUntilEnded();
  console.log(stream);
  if (!vid.captureStream) {
    const ctx = new AudioContext();
    const dest = ctx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    dest.connect(ctx.destination);
  }
};
```

```html
<video src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/Volcano_Lava_Sample.webm" crossorigin controls autoplay></video>
```

Comment: Still an issue in 2023 and this fix works. Thx!